# drupal file sharing

Tags: drupal, file, collaboration

I am finding a drupal module to enable file sharing between users, somebody know someone???

Answer (score 3):

I've been investigating the same thing, and there are a number of options, based on your requirements:

1. You can use node attachments, as described above.
2. You can use the [FileField module](http://drupal.org/project/filefield), which would give finer grain permissions.
3. You can use the [WebFM](http://drupal.org/project/webfm) module for a more file-system oriented approach.
4. Or, you can go whole-hog to a document management system and integrate [KnowledgeTree](http://drupal.org/project/kt) or [Alfresco](http://drupal.org/project/alfresco).

I think I'm leaning toward FileField for simplicity, although I've thought hard about going full DMS.

Comment: WebFM looks awesome for a site I'm speccing up at the moment, thanks for pointing me in the right direction on that one.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to have a look at the /admin/settings/file-system page and then enable the Upload core module (/admin/build/modules) I assume, otherwise, you'll need to clarify your question.
Drupal is not the application for p2p sharing.

Comment: Well I need to construct a site for a customer, he need to upload some files for certain users every month, this is why I need some plugin in drupal to make this file sharing control, do you have any idea???

Comment: I don't see why you can't use the standard modules - let the person upload into some node and then the users who need that upload are given appropriate access rights to the node and can download it...